# How do I setup the bundle besimple/soap-client in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, bundle, soap-client

I'd like to setup besimple/soap-client, I've installed it but I couldn't add it to my appKernel.php, I didn't found anything about adding it to kernel online (https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleSoapClient).

So the question is what should put into my AppKernel.php file?

I tried `new BeSimple\SoapClient\SoapClientBuilder()` but didn't work

Comment: First, how did you install it? `composer require besimple/soap-client "~0.2"` should work. Second, if it's not a Symfony plugin/module you don't need to add it to the Kernel since the Kernel won't know what to do with it. Just `use` the class you want from the Controller you want to use it from.

Comment: I have to add it because of the snippet added into my conf: `http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/soapclient/configuration.html#client-configuration`
Otherwise I got the error: ` Cannot import resource...Looked for namespace "be_simple_soap"....`